# Firefox add-on only inject the content page at popup click - why?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have an Manifest V3 extension that works fine with Chrome/Edge etc. But for Firefox it does not inject the content page before I open the popup window - why?
In the popup I have no code to launch the content page as it has to be done automatically at each page load. I have tried to make different changes to the manifest.json file with no luck.

NB: Using only a temporary install with about:debugging in FF 111

Below current manifest file

```json
{
  "name": "XXX",
  "version": "0.5.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "author": "Benny Nissen",
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; object-src; img-src 'self' data: blob:;"
  },
  "description": "Bla, bla,homepage_url: https://xxx.xx",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/key_icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/key_icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/key_icon128.png"
  },
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "src/browser_action/options.html",
    "open_in_tab": true
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "//service_worker_is_for_chrome_and_scripts_is_for_ff": "stupidity - but please      remove/add relevant //",
    "//service_worker": "src/bg/background.js",
    "scripts": [
      "js/lib/jserror/jserror.js",
      "js/lib/lang/languagedb.js",
      "js/lib/pcrypt.js",
      "js/lib/pcryptapi.js",
      "js/lib/other/prototypes.js",
      "js/lib/other/php.js",
      "js/lib/forge.min.js",
      "js/lib/elliptic.min.js",
      "js/lib/srp6a/thinbus-srp-config.js",
      "js/lib/srp6a/thinbus-srp6a-sha256-versioned.js",
      "js/pcrypt_extension.js",
      "js/pcrypt_shared.js",
      "src/bg/background.js"
    ]
  },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icons/key_icon16.png",
      "48": "icons/key_icon48.png",
      "128": "icons/key_icon128.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Password Crypt",
    "default_popup": "src/browser_action/popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "notifications",
    "geolocation",
    "storage",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "exclude_matches": [
        "https://*.facebook.com/settings*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "src/inject/inject.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    },
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://facebook.com/settings*",
        "https://www.facebook.com/settings*"
      ],
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [
        "src/inject/inject.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "icons/chevron-left.svg",
        "icons/eye.svg",
        "icons/key.svg",
        "icons/key_icon.png",
        "icons/link.svg",
        "icons/settings.svg",
        "icons/settings_black.svg",
        "icons/user.svg"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The only explanation is a bug in Firefox or a problem in your code for content script and/or popup that manifests only in Firefox.

Comment: Firefox V3 manifest is so buggy at the moment, that it makes you cry.